# Javascript - way to convert align= into float:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for an HTML newsletter I have to use the deprecated align attribute to position images - this works fine on the email, but in IE, the align attribute has no effect, so is it possible to target any elements containing align, and convert it to float? The content is being created in a CMS - I'd prefer to avoid asking the user to add classes to images if it could be avoided. Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but this might help: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @JúlioSantos - Very useful link, Júlio. Thanks for that!

Comment: With JavaScript? Running in an email? No chance.

Comment: Not in email. In IE. The email contains a link to view the newsletter in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the HTML is destined for a web page and not an online email client; To target all images that have the align attribute and convert it to float, you'd need something like the following:

```js
$('img[align]').each(function(){

    // perform conversion
    if($(this).attr('align') == 'left')
        $(this).css('float', 'left');
    else if $(this).attr('align') == 'right')
        $(this).css('float', 'right');

    // remove old align tag
    $(this).removeAttr('align');
});
```

Add more conversions if needed, I only added `left` and `right` as an example.

The reasons for explicitly converting each possible value is because `middle`, `top` and `bottom` aren't valid values for `float`. You'll probably have to modify the CSS property `vertical-align`, but don't quote me on that one.

Comment: Not what the OP was looking for. They are wanting to do something like preserve the value of the align attribute, remove the align attribute, and add the float attribute with the equivalent value instead. However as floats are not supported by Outlook, it is a deal-breaker for a lot of people sending HTML email.

Comment: @JimH. - Ahh, now I see. Thanks for clearing that up. Updated code in answer.